# Checking null value in meteor template

Tags: html, templates, meteor

I am using meteor. I have a template which looks like this,

```
<template name="SearchAct">
{{#each SearchPerson}}
    <div class="result"><!--This is one search result box-->
        <div class="resultContent">
            <img src={{payload.pic_square}} alt="profile photo" class="floatLeft" />
            <p>{{payload.uid}}</p>
            <span class="floatLeft">
                {{payload.first_name}}
                <br/>
                {{payload.last_name}}
            </span>
            <input type="checkbox" class="floatRight" />
            <h4>Tennis</h4>
            <span class="age_location">
                {{#if payload.birthday}}
                    {{payload.birthday}},
                {{/if}}
                {{#if payload.sex}}
                    {{payload.sex}}
                {{/if}}
                <br/>
                {{#if payload.hometown_location}}
                    {{payload.hometown_location.city}},
                    {{payload.hometown_location.state}},
                    {{payload.hometown_location.country}}
                {{/if}}
            </span>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <a href="#" class="clear" onclick="renderProfile({{payload.uid}});">See Their Details</a>  
        </div><!-- End of resultContent--> 
    </div><!-- End of result box-->
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Now I want to check a null value for `{{payload.birthday}}`. Here if I get `null` value, I want to display a message. How could I check a `null` value?

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need an `{{else}}` in there:

```
<span class="age_location">
    {{#if payload.birthday}}
        {{payload.birthday}}
    {{else}}
        No birthday found
    {{/if}}
</span>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a concern, but simply using `{{else}}` will only check if a value is "falsy"; so `payload.birthday` could be `false`, `""` or other values that don't evaluate as true and `{{else}}` will be evaluated. If you want to explicitly check whether the `payload.birthday` is null, as opposed to other "falsy" values, you need to use a template function or Handlebars helper.

Answer (score 3):

Handlebars (and by extension Meteor) doesn't allow logic inside templates. Therefore, you need to extend your template, or all your project's templates, with a Handlebars helper. Put the following in any client-loaded JavaScript file in your project:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("isNull", function(value) {
  return value === null;
});
```

Then you can use it in your template as a parameter for your `if`:

```
{{#if isNull payload.birthday}}Your birthday is null!{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this, you can use `count` if value `birthday` eql 0 is false, it's work for me

```
<span class="age_location">
    {{#if payload.birthday.count}}
        {{payload.birthday}}
    {{else}}
        you display message
    {{/if}}
</span>
```

ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/Gumkz9VnLYY